# How can I query last 10 data in Influxdb2.0

Tags: database, influxdb

I tried to query the latest 10  of data, but I only saw from the official documentation how to query the latest 1  of data, has anyone tried it?

```
|> last()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two functions:

1. Use the [sort function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/sort/) with the desc flag set to "true":

   |> sort(columns: ["_value"], desc: true)
2. Then use the [limit function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/limit/) to get only 10 rows of the output, which in your case are the 10 latest points since you sorted the output in descending order:

   |> limit(n: 10)